# What is the exact meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning

The encouraging mails were not restricted to readers but also to some of the regular contributors to The Hindu .

Comment: What part of this sentence don't you understand?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence appears in:

> It is heartening to note the approval for my last column, “An Indian global voice,” from the vast readership of this newspaper. The encouraging mails were not restricted to readers but also to some of the regular contributors to The Hindu .

It means that the encouraging mails came from readers of The Hindu as well as regular contributors to The Hindu, meaning writers whose writings appear in The Hindu.

Answer (score 0):

I'll rewrite this sentence. 'The encouraging mails came from, not only readers, but also regular contributors to The Hindu.' Explanation: the people who wrote the laudatory letters were both readers and contributors to the newspaper/magazine, The Hindu. Any other interpretation, such as some off-the-wall censoring or limitation of access to the fan mail defies common sense.